# How can I deploy a secure (HTTPS) Meteor app on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, meteor, heroku, https, ssl-certificate

I would like to deploy my Meteor app to Heroku and make it only accessible through HTTPS. Ideally, I want to do this as cheaply as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Create the Certificate

Run these commands to get certbot-auto. certbot-auto should work on most systems

```
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
chmod 755 certbot-auto
```

This command starts the process of getting your certificate. The `-d` flag allows you to pass in the domain you would like to secure. Alternatively, without the `-d` flag, it will pop up a prompt where you can enter the domain.

```
./certbot-auto certonly --manual -d app.yoursite.com
```

Then it will ask you the following. Do not hit enter.

```
Make sure your web server displays the following content at                                                      
http://app.yoursite.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/SOME-LENGTHY-KEY before continuing:

SOME-LONGER-KEY
```

#### Use Picker

I suggest using this method because on renewal, you will only need to update an environment variable. You can use `public/` as below, but it will require a rebuild of your entire app every time

Run `meteor add meteorhacks:picker`

In a server side file, add the following

```
import { Picker } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';

Picker.route('/.well-known/acme-challenge/:routeKey', (params, request, response) => {
  response.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write(process.env.SSL_PAGE_KEY)
  response.end();
});
```

Then set an environment variable `SSL_PAGE_KEY` to `SOME-LONGER-KEY` with

```
heroku config:set SSL_PAGE_KEY=SOME-LONGER-KEY
```

#### Use public/

Create the directory path in your `public` folder. If you don't have one, create one.

```
mkdir -p public/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

Then create the file `SOME-LENGTHY-KEY` and place `SOME-LONGER-KEY` inside it

```
echo SOME-LONGER-KEY > public/.well-known/acme-challenge/SOME-LENGTHY-KEY
```

Commit and push that change to your Heroku app.

```
git push heroku master
```

Now hit enter to continue the verification process. You should receive a message like this

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.yoursite.com/fullchain.pem. Your cert will
   expire on 2016-04-11. To obtain a new version of the certificate in
   the future, simply run Let's Encrypt again.
```

## Upload the Certificate

To upload your certificates to Heroku, first enable the SSL Beta

```
heroku labs:enable http-sni -a your-app
heroku plugins:install heroku-certs
```

Then add your `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` to Heroku.

```
sudo heroku _certs:add /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.yoursite.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.yoursite.com/privkey.pem
```

You can verify that the certificate was uploaded with

```
heroku _certs:info
```

## Change your DNS Settings

Update your DNS to point to `app.yoursite.com.herokudns.com`

## Verify SSL is working

To check that SSL is set up, run the following. `-v` gives you verbose output. `-I` shows the document info only. `-H` passes a header to the URL. The header we're passing ensures that a cache is not being used and will ensure you get your new certificate and not an old one.

```
curl -vI https://app.yoursite.com -H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
```

Check that the output contains the following

```
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=SF; O=SFDC; OU=Heroku; CN=app.yoursite.com
```

If the `subject` line does not contain `CN=app.yoursite.com`, wait 5 to 10 minutes and try again. If it does, you're almost good to go.

## Make Meteor Specific Changes

To finish up the process, you'll want to change your `ROOT_URL` environment variable to the new `https` version.

```
heroku config:set ROOT_URL=https://app.yoursite.com
```

Then you'll want to ensure that your users are always using SSL with the `force-ssl` package

```
meteor add force-ssl
```

Lastly, if you have any OAuth logins set up in your app (Facebook, Google, etc), you'll want to provide them with the new `https` version of your URL.

## Renewal

Run `certbot-auto` again

```
./certbot-auto certonly --manual -d app.yoursite.com
```

It **may** prompt you for the same endpoint with the same content. If it does, just hit enter. If it does not, you will need to repeat the above steps.

It will then create new certificate files, which you will upload to Heroku with

```
heroku certs:update /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.yoursite.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.yoursite.com/privkey.pem
```

Then to confirm, run the **Verify SSL is working** commands above

Sources

- https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntutrusty-other
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-beta
- https://themeteorchef.com/blog/securing-meteor-applications/

Comment: Yes, it's a beta feature but it's available to anyone who wishes to use it. https://blog.heroku.com/announcing_heroku_free_ssl_beta_and_flexible_dyno_hours

Comment: Sorry I had to delete my previous comment, it had my client name in it, here it is  : 
`heroku labs:enable http-sni -a your-app` does not work for everybody yet as this is a beta feature. Instead you can get the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/` folder and add them in your Heroku dashboard manually

Comment: I confirm the command does not work for me, from France, I have a message saying that this feature does not exist or is not available. Everything else worked perfectly, thanks a lot for this answer :)

Comment: This didn't work for me, getting warnings about needing to run `su: must be run from a terminal`