# Heroku install letsencrypt - su: must be run from a terminal

Tags: python, bash, ssl, heroku

I am trying to create an ssl certificate for [my website](http://www.monteurzimmer-1a.de/) to get the green lock.

While reaseacrhing how to do that (never done anything with SSL certificates before) I encountered [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). But I cant figure out how to install it on my server.

I have my application on heroku and a custom domain at a random webhoster. I point this domain via CNAME DNS to my heroku application.

As far as I understand the whole SSL thing has to be configured with heroku, because the data is also there.

I have tried a few things which all didnt worked. But this attempt seems to be close:

I created a folder "letsencrypt" in my app localy

I logged in to heroku via CMD

I pushed everything to heroku `git push heroku master`

I used `heroku run bash` to access the folder I created

I entered the folder which I just created `cd letsencrypt`

I cloned letsencrypt into this folder `git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt`

I went again into `cd letsencrypt`

I used `./letsencrypt-auto --help`

Which gave me:

```
"sudo" is not available, will use "su" for installation steps...
Bootstrapping dependencies for Debian-based OSes...
su: must be run from a terminal
apt-get update hit problems but continuing anyway...
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Comment: https://github.com/substrakt/letsencrypt-heroku

Comment: Try following the instructions on [my question/answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348340/how-can-i-deploy-a-secure-https-meteor-app-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: have not tried this yet, but:*

[This](https://medium.com/@franxyzxyz/setting-up-free-https-with-heroku-ssl-and-lets-encrypt-80cf6eac108e#.z9148h2gw) seems to be a pretty comprehensive doc.

Comment: Those instructions does not work here, precisely due to this `su` issue. Actually I think you can't have super user access on an Heroku bash, since it is a shared hosting. @merlinpatt [answer is of great help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348340/how-can-i-deploy-a-secure-https-meteor-app-on-heroku) even for non-Meteor users